# How to share memory buffer across sessions in Django?

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I want to have one party (or more) sends a stream of data via HTTP request(s). Other parties will be able to receive the same stream of data in almost real-time.

The data stream should be accessible across sessions (according to access control list).

How can I do this in Django? If possible I would like to avoid database access and use in memory buffer (along with some synchronization mechanism)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`posix_ipc`](http://semanchuk.com/philip/posix_ipc/) or [`sysv_ipc`](http://semanchuk.com/philip/sysv_ipc/) to use shared memory.